# Cmake: change the compiler of multiple projects?

Tags: c++, cmake

#### The problem

I would like to update the compiler of multiple C++ projects.
And I would like to automate it as much as I can.

The structure is:

```
-Folder 1
 - CmakeList.txt
-Folder 2
 - CmakeList.txt
-Folder 3
 - CmakeList.txt
```

I have dozens of projects that **need** to be updated because of LTO constraints (static libs), and raw language update. And it is a chore to do it by hand.
Cmake points to Ninja.

I want the projects and static libs to remain independent, in their own directories, like the structure above.

#### Cmake excerpt

```
project(${APP_NAME} LANGUAGES CXX)
add_library(${APP_NAME} STATIC ${SOURCES})

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS ON)
set(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES "Debug" "Release")

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS -fuse-ld=mold)
set(CMAKE_INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION_RELEASE ON)
```

#### First solution:

create a script mimicking what my IDE does and apply it for every folder.
That could be a working solution but I find it error prone.

#### Second solution:

Maybe having a driving cmake at the root and consider the other cmake like individual subs?
[using Cmake subdirectories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_subdirectory.html)

I am not sure where to go with that but it sounds like it could help. I could set the compiler and other common definitions (like C++/Cmake min version) in the parent and only reload that file in my IDE and let Cmake do all the dirty work? Is that it?

#### Third solution:

create a script to replace in textual files (in the Cmake cache..) the reference to the compiler and archiver and so on. => **NO.**

#### Question

Not sure what the best -headache free?- approach is. Now, what would be the best Cmake way to reload all the libs with the updated compiler ?
From then on, I already have my script to call Ninja on all the libs.

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE.html

Comment: Thanks not sure why, setting set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE cmake_compiler.cmake) with that file having set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/g++-13) leads to an infinite loop when above add_subdirectory directives

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_guard.html `setting set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` Do not `set()` it, it shouldn't be inside code. Pass it the command line. Overall, you should not hardcode anything compiler specific in cmake sources, all configuration is user specific.

Comment: Yes but I need an automated way to set the compiler of multiple sub projects, and passing the compiler only once. Otherwise, I will end up creating my own script and be done with it. Too complicated..

Comment: Then you might also be searching for https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html , but for me `I will end up creating my own script` that's what I do, just `export CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=thisfile` and execute cmake then.

Comment: I just created an answer, it is highly debatable, I know, but it did the trick..

Answer (score 0):

(debatable solution)
**APPARENTLY,**

setting `set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/your_compiler CACHE PATH "" FORCE)`
enabled to do what I want.

Again, I need to control the compiler at the Cmake generation stage because I have some scripts that call Ninja later on. And having a different set of compiler messed up my builds with LTO. I want to clean that mess without the process to be too manual.

It is not the recommended way as I understood; but I need to make it work nonetheless.